# How to set unique for specific field from specific table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this where i have all features from database:

```
$features = Feature::all();
```

User can add new additional feature that will be added in this table, but i want to validate so if user enter something that is already in databse to get a message. So name need to be unique. Any suggestion how can i do that?

I tried this but it save it anyway.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'unique:features',
    ]);
```

Comment: Make sure your column name in your `feature` table is `name`.

Comment: it is name i checked twice

Comment: What are the contents of $request->all();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $feauturescheck= Feauture::where('Columname', '=',Input::get('input'))->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique)

> **unique:table,column,except,idColumn**
>
> The field under validation must be unique in a given database table. If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.
>
> Specifying A Custom Column Name:
>
> `'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'`

You may need to specify the column to be checked against.